# Scss/ css dynamic content

Tags: javascript, html, css

**HTML:**

```
<div class="card"></div>
```

**Scss**

```
.card{
  &:before {
    content: 'Text inserted before via CSS';
   }
}
```

This adds content before the div. but how can i add the content from SCSS.

This was not working

```
.card{ content: 'Text inserted via CSS';  }
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is quite confusing.. your scss is working fine I think. `card{ content: 'Text inserted via CSS';  }` this code won't work, you need to add &:before then content property

Comment: yes `:before` and `:after` works fine. but I  want to update only the content. Any work arounds in css

Comment: 1. Content won't work without before or after. 2. If wanna change text of content, add a data attribute in html like `data-text="custom text"` then in content you can use it like this `content: attr(data-text)`. But note here also you will have to use before or after.

Answer (score 1):

The content property only applies to CSS pseudo-elements such as `:before` and `:after`

You should use JQuery for this purpose:

```
$('.card').text("Text inserted before via JQuery");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying to do in css/scss, with out other library

Comment: @upog But I tell you that surely you can not do it with css/scss.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```css
.card:before{
      content:attr(data-content);
    }
```

```html
 <div class="card" data-content="Text inserted before via CSS"></div>
```